# Run ts-node in systemd service

Tags: systemd, systemctl, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to create a service to run a typescript file.

This is what's in my service file so far:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service that runs the Parenti Bot
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=abias
ExecStart=/home/abias/.local/share/pnpm/ts-node /home/abias/projects/lemmygrad-parenti-bot/bot.ts
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I added the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env ts-node` at the top of the file `bot.ts`. I also made sure to run `sudo chmod +x bot.ts`. Despite doing all this, I get the following output when I run `sudo systemctl status` on my service:

```
× parentibot.service - Service that runs the Parenti Bot
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/parentibot.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-12-08 17:50:32 EST; 11s ago
   Duration: 6ms
    Process: 283671 ExecStart=/home/abias/.local/share/pnpm/ts-node /home/abias/projects/lemmygrad-parenti-bot/bot.ts (code=e>
   Main PID: 283671 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 3ms

Dec 08 17:50:32 fedora systemd[1]: parentibot.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 08 17:50:32 fedora systemd[1]: Stopped parentibot.service - Service that runs the Parenti Bot.
Dec 08 17:50:32 fedora systemd[1]: parentibot.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 08 17:50:32 fedora systemd[1]: parentibot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 08 17:50:32 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start parentibot.service - Service that runs the Parenti Bot.
```

What could I be doing wrong?

**Edit**: Output of running `sudo journalctl -xeu yourService.service`

```
Dec 08 17:50:32 fedora systemd[1]: Stopped parentibot.service - Service that runs the Parenti Bot.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit parentibot.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit parentibot.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 22216 and the job result is done.
Dec 08 17:50:32 fedora systemd[1]: parentibot.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 08 17:50:32 fedora systemd[1]: parentibot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ The unit parentibot.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 08 17:50:32 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start parentibot.service - Service that runs the Parenti Bot.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit parentibot.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit parentibot.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 22216 and the job result is failed.
```

**Edit 2**: The contents of `bot.ts` can be seen [here](https://codeberg.org/SleeplessOne1917/Lemmy-Parenti-Bot/src/branch/main/bot.ts).

**Edit 3**: I just ran `journalctl` and saw this error: `parentibot.service: Failed to locate executable /home/abias/.local/share/pnpm/ts-node`. That looks like it might be the problem, but it raises the question: why is the executable (which I checked to make sure exists) not being found?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo journalctl -xeu yourService.service`?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I updated the question with the requested information.

Comment: I see nothing relevant, maybe the problem is about how you run the ts script or what the script does. Can you provide the content of your ts file: `/home/abias/projects/lemmygrad-parenti-bot/bot.ts`?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon updated the question with a link the the repo that has the source code.

Comment: Ok, I will give a check. About your service try adding this line: `StandardError=file:/home/user/tsbot.log`. And restart your service. After that (it will fail) check the logs in `/home/user/tsbot.log` and if you see any content then add it to your question.

Comment: I think your main problem is that you missed: `RemainAfterExit=yes`. Add that line in the `[Service]` section. I see `Start request repeated too quickly.` in your logs and what is happening is that your `ts` project keeps running but the service is taking as `Finished` and therefore the service proceeds to  keep restarting.

Comment: I tried adding `StandardError=<path to log>` but that caused a different error and no logs were written. I get the same error when I add `RemainAfterExit=yes` to the service section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141190/discussion-between-anthony-bias-and-edgar-magallon).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the problem was. It turns out `/home/abias/.local/share/pnpm/ts-node` was only the location of `ts-node` for my own user. The correct location of ts-node to use was `/usr/bin/local/ts-node`.